# How to set another control style when they are created in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

The following shows two buttons. When the mouse is over the second button, I would like to change the firsts borderbrush to white.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModuleCollection}"  >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0">
                <Button Content="{Binding ModuleName}" Template="{StaticResource navModuleButton}"/>
                <Button Template="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I believe could possibly be done with a datatrigger on the first button as follows, but in order to do that I need to name the second button, not sure how to dynamically name.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=closeBtn1, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="btnBorder" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

How to do this?

**[EDIT]**

This is the template for the first button where you'll see btnBorder is the border I would like to change the color of.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="navModuleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="btnBorder" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,7,0">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="Border1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderThickness="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5" CornerRadius="0,0,7,0">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5"  EndPoint="1,0.5">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
            <DockPanel Name="myContentPresenterDockPanel">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter" Margin="10,0,21,0"  
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding  Content}" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  TextBlock.Foreground="White" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="btnBorder" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property ="Opacity" Value="0.30" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border1">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                <GradientStop Color="#837C7C7C" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#83343434" Offset="0.99496336996337187"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#83343434" Offset="0.523844744998591"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#837C7C7C" Offset="0.48045224006762494"/>
                            </GradientStopCollection>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" TargetName="Grid"/>
            <Setter Property="BitmapEffect" TargetName="Border1">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Blue"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Why you want to "dynamically name" the second button (and what you mean by that) ?

Comment: You see the two buttons, when I am hovering over the second I want the first to highlight it's border. I have a ControlTemplate for each of the buttons, in the templates there is a border called btnBorder that I want to change the color of.

Comment: When referencing another control via a datatrigger you need to use the name of the other control don't you? As these buttons are dynamically created from the ItemsControl a unique name would have to be created dynamically.. I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SourceName` property in a trigger, like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Button x:Name="btnModule"
                Content="{Binding ModuleName}" 
                Template="{StaticResource navModuleButton}"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnClose"
                Template="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"/>
     </Grid>

     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
         <Trigger SourceName="btnClose" Property="IsMouseOver">
             <Setter TargetName="btnModule" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
         </Trigger>
     </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Don't worry about the names, WPF takes care of that, since the `DataTemplate` has it's own [Name Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit:** your button ControlTemplate is wrong.

A `ControlTemplate` should be defined in such a way that the properties of the Visual elements inside of it are *"tied"* to the properties of the `Control` the template is applied to.

In other words, your `btnBorder` should depend on the properties of the "parent templated item" the Control to which template is applied, in this case, `btnModule`.

For that purpose, a common approach is to use a [`TemplateBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the ControlTemplate, like this:

```
 <Border x:Name="btnBorder" 
         RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
         BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
         CornerRadius="0,0,7,0"
         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"> <!-- See the TemplateBinding here -->
```

this will bind the `btnBorder.BorderBrush` property to the parent's BorderBrush (in this case `btnModule.BorderBrush`)

Comment: that makes sense but I tried it without success, am I able to target the component btnBorder specifically? I posted an edit above which includes the btnModule ControlTemplate.

Comment: @Hank no, you can't access UI elements from a different NameScope. See my edit

Comment: Actually still related to this, hypothetically, in the template there are two borders what if I wanted to change brushes on both?

Comment: @Hank see [VisualStateManager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx)